# Reloading a div using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I searched SO to help create the following request to refresh a `div` at specific intervals.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#trigger-newsfeed").load("getNewsfeed.php");
           var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
              $("#trigger-newsfeed").load('getNewsfeed.php');
           }, 4000);
    });
```

This works although I was wondering if this could be made more efficient by the use of Ajax (if it is not using Ajax already without me realising).

I had tried using some other Ajax code to do this which also did work, however, other solutions would wait for the interval to finish then load the data. So for example if the interval was set to 5 seconds, each time that page is visisted, a user would have to wait for 5 seconds and then it would load; so this is the only snippet I had found worked best by relaying the information *first* then refreshing by the interval; although I am not sure if it is the best use of jquery to do this.

I ask this because the majority of searches made online regarding `div` refreshes all point to the usage of Ajax.

Comment: You are currently using Ajax, though it could be made more efficient by not using setInterval, and instead using setTimeout and the success callback.

Comment: Unsure as to why my question had been downvoted; but anyway, thank you @KevinB, I will look into setTimeout and make the above code more efficient :)

Comment: I wasn't the dv, but my guess is it doesn't really belong here, there's a CodeReview stackexchange for these types of questions. http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I thought it would be better to place here as I wanted to gain some knowledge on Ajax also (in the case that the function in the question was not Ajax) and therefore discover better alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have will work, but if the network connection/computer is slow or the server gets bogged down for whatever reason, the requests could start to backup, and if that happens too much, it could crash the browser.

To fix that, use a `setTimeout` instead of an interval so that it will only request new data 4 seconds after it receives the response from the previous request.

```
function refreshNewsFeed() {
    $("#trigger-newsfeed").load("getNewsfeed.php",function(){
        setTimeout(refreshNewsFeed,4000);
    });
}
$(document).ready(refreshNewsFeed);
```

Comment: I was just modifying my answer to do that same thing, as I see your point about potentially stacking calls if the response takes 4s to return.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed. Thanks for understanding my question!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loadNewsFeed = function () {
        $("#trigger-newsfeed").load('getNewsfeed.php');
    };
    loadNewsFeed();
    var refreshId = window.setInterval(loadNewsFeed, 4000);
});
```

In .ready we declare a function and assign it to the variable loadNewsFeed. Then we execute the function. Then, we setup the interval to execute every 4 seconds after that.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain this? Is this a more efficient version of the jquery function I am using at the moment?

Comment: @user1888378 It's less redundant, but it's no more efficient.

Comment: @KevinB, what's not efficient?  It could be reloading data the instant it finishes the last load...but that's wasteful of bandwidth, in my opinion.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't efficient, i said it isn't more efficient. The problem with it is if the network conditions are slow and it takes more than 4 seconds to get a response, ajax requests are going to back up and eventually crash the browser. The original code has that same problem.

Comment: @CaffGeek So could you suggest another form of implementing this? Or would this be acceptable. This is a small scale project also